# vips gem clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, vips

I'm getting this error when having the gem `gem "vips"` in my `Gemfile`:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I have llvm and vips installed

I have also opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/320

Comment: Don't use the `vips` gem. It's called `ruby-vips`.